# Bootstrap-modal: Partial view displayed in modal-body

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm attempting to load a partial view inside a bootstrap model. Since I have an existing form in the parent page and another in the partial view. I cannot decide to put the forms on one pages, because then there will be a form within a form.

Below is my checkbox in the parent page, when checked it will display the model dialog:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputNewBornKMC" value="inputNewBornKMC" id="inputNewBornKMCCheckbox"> New Born
```

Below is the modal dialog in the parent page:

```
                        <div Class="modal fade" id="inputNewBornKMC" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Search Newborn's Mother</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="AddGP">Save changes</button>*@
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- Modal content-->
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- Modal -->
```

In the javascript, I put the following code to load the modal dialog:

```
        $('#inputNewBornKMCCheckbox').on('change', function (e) {
        var _this = $(this);

        // if checked
        if (_this.is(':checked')) {
            $('#inputNewBornKMC').modal({
                keyboard: false,
                remote: '/controller/AddPartialRegistration'
            }).show();

        $('#inputNewBornKMCCheckbox').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('data-target', '#inputNewBornKMC');
                $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

            });

       }
```

Which will call an action in controller to display the partial view:

```
public ActionResult AddPartialRegistration()
    {
        return PartialView("_PartialRegistration");
    }
```

In _PartialRegistration page:

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmSearchMother" role="form" >

                    Mother's MRN
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="popupMotherMRN" name="popupMotherMRN" />
                    IC/ID No
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="popupICNo" name="popupICNo" />
                    Mother's Name
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="popupMotherName" name="popupMotherName" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="SearchMother" >Search</button>
                </form>
                <br />
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="LoadMotherDetailsTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>Mother's MRN</th>
                            <th>Mother's IC No</th>
                            <th>Mother's Name</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
```

I've tried numerous ways in which people apply partial views, but none have worked. I'm unsure as to how to make the partial view be inserted in the modal-body inside of the modal dialog. This dialog can be displayed when checking the checkbox, but I'm unsure as to how to load the partial view in the modal-body.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer so dont expect much.

I would say the best way to inject a partial view is the way you are trying as well.

I would say you call AJAX and return the partial view data via the controller.
This is an code taken from a use case I wrote:

```
function showVideo(e) {
        alert('#' + $(e).attr("id"));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Games/_GameModal/' + $(e).attr("id"),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('#' + $(e).attr("id"));
                $('#deleteConfirmation').html(data);
                $('#deleteConfirmation').modal();
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my Partial View cshtml:

```
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
          hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal-title text-center">@Model.gameName</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">By @Model.publisher</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center">Content Rating: @Model.Contentrating</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4 class="text-center">Trailer</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="@Model.trailerLink" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <h4 class="text-center">Description</h4>
        <p>@Model.description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the container I am injecting into:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

If you want to inject into the modal body you would replace the '#deleteConfirmation' with the id of you div of the modal-body and inject HTML data into it.

I hope this was helpful and I am sorry if it wasnt. Just trying to help

Thanks,
Narendran P

Comment: Thanks anyways for your good intention in helping :) I don't quite understand what is the function of aria-labelledby? Is it important?

Comment: it is important if you want visually disabled people to use a screen reader and know what is going on in your page